# VMWare Vsphere can't ping the SMTP Server

Tags: vmware-vsphere

On the VM i can ping the smtp.gmail.com just fine, however when I'm using the Putty to connect to my vsphere it's always "Destination Host Unreachable". Google the issue and found a good article to enable the "File and Printer Sharing (Echo Reuqeust -ICMPv4-In)" rule but as I said nothing worked.

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @MikaelH I'm trying to send an email notification whenever a vSphere alarm is triggered. However when it is triggered in my case nothing is being sent. I'm assuming that it might results that the vSphere is not establishing a connection to smtp gmail server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A local firewall rule for ICMPv4 echo requests would decide whether your own host responds to such requests or not - not whether it's allowed to send them.

Do you have a network administrator who has attempted to harden your management network? If so, speak to them about opening up for outgoing mail from your vCenter appliance.
Otherwise you'll simply have to start troubleshooting your network environment:

- Do you get ping responses from other hosts in the subnet of your vCenter appliance?
- Do you get ping responses from hosts in other subnets in your infrastructure?
- Do you get ping responses from hosts belonging to your ISP (if they are configured to respond)?

Once you've solved that problem, if you're serious about using gmail to relay your notifications, you'll have to configure the email authentication settings found in Configuration -> Advanced Settings -> `mail.smtp.password`, `mail.smtp.port`, and `mail.smtp.username`, in addition to setting the Configuration -> General -> `Mail server` and `Mail sender` settings.